# How to inflate new layout on OnRecievedError in Webview?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, layout-inflater

I am trying to inflate new **error.xml** layout whenever `webview` catches error and executes `onRecievedError()` method. I am half way through but the problem is i get both the view... my **error.xml** view as well as *"webpage not found error "*view so please help me with this.

Fragment.java

```
public class menu_1 extends Fragment {
private WebView wv;
private TextView tv;
RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);


    wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag1_web);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///res/raw/web1.html");
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            LayoutInflater inflater1=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View v=inflater1.inflate(R.layout.show_error,null);
            view.addView(v);
       }

});
    return v;
}



@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Menu 1");
}


}
```

show_error.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/errorText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Problem Loading Page"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/frag1_web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Below is the view i am receiving on the run.]

Comment: you can call new activity and set error.xml to it on get error

Comment: post layout file of your fragment in which webview is used

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya I am getting this webview inside fragment so dont want to call new activity just to show error...

Comment: @Pehlaj added fragment file.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update fragment layout**

Fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/frag1_web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Problem Loading Page"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Hide webview on Error & show text view**

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanax alot @Pehlaj :) It worked ... can i play around with imageview and other widgets using the same method . and setting visibility when i need it .Will this things will work too.

Comment: Yes, you can show/hide any view based on success/error of webview